# Chrome - Notify User to install your extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't remember what website it was, but when I browsed the homepage with Google Chrome I was  notified that the site had an extension available for Google Chrome, with a button to install.

I can't find the documentation of how to notify users (that are using chrome) that the extension is available when they browse my site (the extension is related to my site's content). I'd like to know how to prompt the user to install or navigate to the extension page with a native Google Chrome notification.

I believe Firefox extensions can be installed in this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the yellow infobar style notification like [page2rss uses](http://page2rss.com/page?url=www.google.com/). There is no official support for such a notification. They have it implemented in HTML on their site and trigger it based on browser user agent.

I would recommend against implementing notifications that mimic chrome design and make users think it is a notification from the browser though. Just have a download button next to a Chrome icon that asks the user to install.

---

**Update:** Chrome now supports [inline installation](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/inline_installation.html) which makes it very easy to check if an extension is installed and if not install with just a couple of clicks.

**Update 2:** Inline installation is no [longer available](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/inline_faq).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if Chrome natively supported notifying users of available extensions. http://www.independent.co.uk/ is an example of a site that I saw...should have realized that they were mimicking native UI ;)

Comment: which part in the page http://page2rss.com/page?url=www.google.com/ to trigger the notification bar on the top of the chrome browser and I wonder is there anything similar with Firefox?

Comment: As of 06/12/2018, inline chrome extension installation is deprecated. see FAQ for more details: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/inline_faq

Answer (score 0):

check the user agent of the browser that is viewing the page and display accordingly :-)