# How to trigger the "yellow prompt" in Google Chrome or Chromium?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Sometimes while browsing websites using Chrome, you can see a yellow prompt showup. How can I trigger that prompt for my own websites?

For example try going to the [The Independent's website](http://www.independent.co.uk/) and you will be prompted "The Independent now has a Google Chrome Extension. Get the latest news on the topics you like, direct to your browser."

I have previously seen this prompt on Google.com as well, however I assumed that that was something internal for google only websites. This is the first time I have seen the prompt for Non-Google owned websites.

[image: Screenshot showing The Independent's website]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a custom look-a-like they've made. Take a look at their javascript file here: http://www.independent.co.uk/independent.co.uk/editorial/javascript/tb.js

It does most of the work. You might be able to get some ideas from there :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need to check this question: [Chrome - Notify User to install your extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277641/chrome-notify-user-to-install-your-extension)

Looks like there are no standard API for defining extension available for particular site – so you need to imitate such behavior with JS.

If I made a mistake, feel free to correct me in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [Infobars API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.infobars.html), but this feature is only available for extensions.